# Alternative to SET statements in View query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view

I wrote a select statement to use as a view in Tsql. I really would like to use `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL  OFF` at the top of my query in order to be able to concatenate with nulls. However using SET statements in views isn't allowed.

The only option I am seeing is to go through my query and wrap all variables that could be concatenated as nulls with `ISNULL(variable, '')`. There has to be a better way.

(I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.)

Comment: Prior to SQL Server 2012 with `CONCAT`, using `ISNULL` was how it was done.

Comment: I sucked it up and peppered the query with ISNULLs all over the place.

Comment: that is a pain you pay for concatenations, and a good reason to avoid them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`

   > In a future version of SQL Server `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` will always
   >   be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to `OFF` will
   >   generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work,
   >   and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.
2. `ISNULL()` `COALESCE()` or `CONCAT`